# How to write a program in Python where a range of numbers is compared to numbers in a list and whenever there is a match, a count is increased

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range, comparison

Context, I am super new to coding. Starting with Python. First and foremost, I'd like to apologise if I post questions in an unacceptable way.

So, the problem is, I have numbers in a list and I need to compare these numbers with a range of numbers (basically the range between the mean and the std deviation of the numbers in the list. What I want to do is to count how many numbers from the list are matching with the numbers in the range.

```
    add = 0
for count in (standard, meany+1):
    if count == data[]:
        add += 1
    else:
        add += 0
```

I tried this and I am getting a syntax error, which I knew would happen because I am not very aware of the syntax but I hope the intent/algorithm behind my code is right.

If someone could help me get it sorted, it'd be a huge help. And any sort of tips and tricks are welcome regarding anyhting.

Thank you.

Comment: You have the *code* that's good - but it's helpful to have some input and expected output to share, so people can help you more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In my example, `list[]` would be the list of numbers you want to compare to.

With `rangeMIN` being the minimum of the range,
and `rangeMAX` as the maximum of the range.

If we loop through the length of the list each time we loop through one iteration of the range, we can detect if a number coexists in the specified range `(rangeMIN, rangeMAX)`, and as a value in list `lst_value`

```py
lst_value = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
rangeMIN = 0
rangeMAX = 5
for count in range (rangeMIN, rangeMAX):
    for num in range(len(lst_value)):
        if list[count] == num:
            print(f"{count} is equal to {num}!")
```